# PageName property is missing in SSRS RDLC file

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, reporting-services, export-to-excel

i am developing report with RDLC file type from VS2010 IDE but i found tablix member has no pagename property like

[image]

so please tell me this property is really missing in rdlc file or it has another name. my intention was like export data to excel. if i need to set sheet name programmatically then i have to set expression on pagename property and that is why i was looking into tablix member property. so if anyone knows how to handle this situation working with rdlc file then please tell me. thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you write "PageName"? does it the report name? the ASP.NET Page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to see Tablix Member properties, then go to group and find PageName, then you just have to place him or the expression dataset field. excuse my bad English